# SQL: 4 Points alternating up and down

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a query that identifies 4 consecutive points alternating up and down. I have included test data, expected results, and my query below. My query does not produce the correct results and I am having trouble understating why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

E.g. Wk 5 has 4 points alternating up and down (wk, 2,3,4,5).

```
;CREATE TABLE #B (Wk INT, Rate DECIMAL(18,4))
;INSERT INTO #B (Wk, Rate) VALUES 
(1, 0.0),   
(2, 0.1),
(3, 0.2),   
(4, 0.1),   
(5, 0.3),--1    
(6, 0.2),--1    
(7, 0.1),   
(8, 0.3),   
(9, 0.2),--1    
(10,0.1)

;WITH StartingWk AS (
    SELECT Wk CurrentWk, Rate CurrentRate
    FROM #B
), A AS (
    SELECT b1.Wk, b1.Rate,CASE WHEN b1.Rate > B2.Rate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS inc
    FROM #B b1
    LEFT JOIN #B b2 ON b1.Wk = b2.Wk+1
), B AS (
    SELECT StartingWk.CurrentWk, A.*
    FROM StartingWk
    LEFT JOIN A ON A.Wk >= StartingWk.CurrentWk aND A.Wk < StartingWk.CurrentWk+4
), C AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT B1.CurrentWk, B1.Wk, CASE WHEN B1.inc != ISNULL(b2.inc,1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS YN 
    FROM B B1 
    LEFT JOIN B B2 ON B1.Wk = B2.Wk-1 AND B1.inc != ISNULL(b2.inc,1) 
)
SELECT C1.CurrentWk, MAX(C1.Wk) EndingWk, SUM(YN)YN
FROM C C1
GROUP BY C1.CurrentWk
HAVING SUM(YN) = 4
```

Expected Results:

```
WK |Rate|YN|
------------
|1 |0.0 |0 |
|2 |0.1 |0 |
|3 |0.2 |0 | 
|4 |0.1 |0 |
|5 |0.3 |1 | 
|6 |0.2 |1 | 
|7 |0.1 |0 | 
|8 |0.3 |0 | 
|9 |0.2 |1 | 
|10|0.4 |0 |
```

Comment: You did a great job posting ddl, sample data and desired output. Well done. What I don't understand though is what you are trying to do. What does "alternating up and down" mean?

Comment: Alternating up and down is an increase in the rate then a decrease in the next rate or vise versa. Wk 5 has 4 rates alternating up and down. Wk 3 is up from 2, 4 is down from 3, and 5 is up from 4. Hope this helps.

Comment: OK. So why is WK 5 YN = 1? I can't make heads or tails of the logic you are trying to achieve here. It goes up, up, up, down, up (and this one is 1 instead of 0). And why is 6 also a 1? Explain the business rules here and we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL 2008 `recursive CTE` might be better option. Query compares each row with 3 previous rows and forms resulting string due to change in `Rate`(1 - increase, -1 - decreases, 0 no change). String with alternating up and down should look like `1-11` or `-11-1`

```
with cte as (
    select
        *, rn = row_number() over (order by wk)
    from
        #B
)
, rcte as (
    select *, 1 step, res = cast('' as varchar(200))
    from cte
    union all
    select
        a.Wk, b.Rate, b.rn, a.step + 1
        , cast(a.res + case when b.Rate > a.Rate then '1' when b.Rate < a.Rate then '-1' else '0' end as varchar(200))
    from
        rcte a
        join cte b on a.rn - 1 = b.rn
    where
        a.step < 4
)
select 
    top 1 with ties Wk, Rate
    , YN = case when res in ('1-11', '-11-1') then 1 else 0 end
from rcte
order by row_number() over (partition by wk order by step desc)
```

Output

```
Wk  Rate    YN
--------------
1   0.0000  0
2   0.0000  0
3   0.0000  0
4   0.0000  0
5   0.1000  1
6   0.2000  1
7   0.1000  0
8   0.3000  0
9   0.2000  1
10  0.1000  0
```

Comment: I am now trying to find 14 points up and down, how can I modify the query that? I tried updating 'a.step <4' to 'a.step <14' but that did not work.

Comment: That's because you should also change `res in ('1-11', '-11-1')` to `res in ('1-11-11-11-11-11-11', '-11-11-11-11-11-11-1')`. I have not checked. But try to play with this string

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE is almost never the most efficient solution.  Assuming the wks are consecutive, you can just join your way to the solution:

```
select w.*,
       (case when w3.rate < w2.rate and w2.rate > w1.rate and w1.rate < w.rate
             then 1
             when w3.rate > w2.rate and w2.rate < w1.rate and w1.rate > w.rate
             then 1
             else 0
        end) as yn
from #wk w left join
     #wk w1
     on w1.wk = w.wk - 1 left join
     #wk w2
     on w2.wk = w.wk - 2 left join
     #wk w3
     on w3.wk = w.wk - 3;
```

In subsequent versions of SQL Server, you would just use `lag()`.